# Jquery trigger on body resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a page that has content that is modified by javascript. I want to create some kind of event listener that triggers when the content's size changes. I do not want this:

```
$(window).resize(...);
```

This triggers when the window size changes - for example when the user re-sizes the browser window. I tried this:

```
$('body').resize(...);
```

However it does not trigger. How can I create an event that triggers when the content causes the page size to change? I am also open to plain javascript solutions.

Comment: be careful doing this, because this can fire off hundreds of events per second

Comment: if content is the only thing that is modified by resize, consider to use http://mediaqueri.es/

Comment: Do you need it as soon as it has changed? Otherwise you get set up intervals to check the size from the previously set, if its changed do your stuff

Comment: @JamieHutber Yep, that's one of my last resorts if I can't find anything else. Either that or find everywhere that modifies the DOM (which is a lot of places) and add a function call.

Comment: So what might cause the content to resize? An AJAX call? Why not just call the function after the AJAX has returned? Or, you could throw a `$("body").trigger("contentresize")` Whenever you do something that will change the flow of the page.

Comment: @Shmiddty Yep, I could do that, but I have a *lot* of places that modify the DOM. If there is no way to do this with an event, I'll do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default jQuery will only let you use that event on `window` but there is at least one [plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/) out there that will let you bind it to other elements. I would recommend using that.

With this you could then do something similar, like

```
$("#unicorns").resize(function(e){
    // do something when #unicorns element resizes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use such approach:

```
$(elem).append('<iframe id="frame0" name="frame0" width=100% height=100% style="position:absolute;top:0px;z-index:-1"></iframe>');
frame0.onresize = function() {
    //..do something ””
}
```

And this will trigger on each elem size change;)